# OdbcDataReader trimming leading zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files, datareader, odbcdatareader

I am trying to read txt file into the database using the following codes in my .net project.

```
var ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[database].ConnectionString;
string strConnString = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + folderPath.Trim() + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False;Readonly=False";
string sql_select;

OdbcConnection conn;
conn = new OdbcConnection(strConnString.Trim());
conn.Open();
OdbcCommand commandRowCount = new OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [" + fileName.Trim() + "]", conn);
sql_select = "select * from [" + file.Trim() + "]";

OdbcCommand commandSourceData = new OdbcCommand(sql_select, conn);
commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = 0;
OdbcDataReader dataReader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
{
    bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
    bc.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[" + tablename.Trim() + "]";
    bc.NotifyAfter = 5000;
    bc.BatchSize = 5000;
    bc.WriteToServer(dataReader);
    bc.Close();
}
```

But the OdbcDataReader is removing the leading zeros in one of the columns (which is nvarchar).
How can I keep the leading zeros ?

Comment: what is the size of `nvarchar` in database?

Comment: @un-lucky, it's nvarchar(100) but the imput data will be at most 3 character so far. usually it will be 001 or 031.

Comment: Can you change the input data to have double quotes just for testing.  "001" instead of 001.  This might lead you down a solution specific to the Text odbc reader.  You are also at the mercy of the BulkCopy behaviors in your code, similar concept.

Comment: So the value changed to `numeric` from `OdbcDataReader` but not in `SqlBulkCopy`?

Comment: I try to use this before the SqlBulkCopy then see the trimming of leading zeros in the table.           OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql_select, conn);
                    DataSet dsSchema = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(dsSchema, 1, 50, "TextDB");

Comment: @SqlSurfer, those data will be uploaded by the client, I can't ask them to change it for all the rows since there will be thousands of rows everyday. so it is not an option for me.